# Unescaped HTML and source code bleeding through CW links

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

[image]

Eeeeek, what happened [there](https://superuser.com/questions/827782/unable-to-copy-install-os-x-yosemite-app-file-to-my-external-hard-drive/827830#827830)?

Seems that for CW posts, the linking is broken. Actually quite nice source code revealing here in the HTML:

```
 2 revs&lt;br&gt;&lt;a href="/users/48078"&gt;slhck&lt;/a&gt;  # Models\PostNoticeType.cs
```

Comment: i'm on it. hold on tight

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A bit was left behind when refactoring to use our new Moonspeak.Complier ™ © ® &copy;

It should be fixed in the incoming deployment.

---

that fixed one bug, but apparently we've uncovered a deeper issue with the new compiler...